# Is there any difference between "color" and "colour"?

Tags: differences, nouns, american-english, british-english, o-ou

What is the difference between *color* and *colour*?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, this word comes to us from the Latin word *color-em*, which was inherited by old French. The o segment in Old French was actually somewhere between [o] and [u] and was represented by the digraph *ou.* When this syllable became accented, it became fronted, represented by *eu* (this the Modern French *couleur*). The corresponding English word of old is the ancestor of *hue*.

The world was adopted directly into Middle English as *colur*; later *colour* from the Old French *color*, *culur*, *colur*; later *colour*; and finally *coulour*, which was the preferred Anglo-French spelling. *Colour* was eventually standardized in post Anglo-French English. Noah Webster's 1828 dictionary is credited with standardizing the latinate *color* in American English.

Answer (score 23):

"Color" is favored in the United states, and "Colour" is favored (I believe) everywhere else.

Here is a [Wikipedia article](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#-our.2C_-or) commenting on "or" vs. "our".

Comment: As an programmer, it takes years of training/swearing to remember to write color in code, yet colour everywhere else ;)

Comment: @jon, always made me wonder why Tim Berners Lee, himself British, used the American spelling throughout HTML, e.g. `<FONT COLOR="#cc6600">` and not `<FONT COLOUR="#cc6600">` and `<TABLE BGCOLOR=...>` and not `<TABLE BGCOLOUR=...>`.

Comment: How about favor and favour? You are using favor, I see.

Comment: @Vaibhav, favor/favour is exactly analogous to color/colour. Being American, mac9416 quite naturally favoured "favor". :-)

Comment: @Edward. I think *American* English is so clearly the native language & lingua franca of computer programming that I don't find it particularly surprising that he chose to use "color". It only makes sense.

Comment: If he had used the British spelling, HTML would be forever earmarked as British.

Comment: The FONT/COLOR tags were introduced by Netscape in a rush to add proprietary features, not by Tim Berners-Lee. The HTML 2.0 spec makes no mention of "COLOR". That first appeared in HTML 3.2